# Nested for-loop math notation

Tags: algorithms

I'm new to writing math notation that describes algorithms and I need to translate some python code. Does the notation structure below correctly describe a nested for-loop that for-each value in p iterates over all other values in p?

[image]

Example code

```
function(p):
    for a in p:
       for b in p:
         // do something with a and b...
```

Comment: Hi there. You use $\Sigma$ in your notation which usually implies a sum e.g. $\Sigma_{i = 0}^{n} i = 0 + 1 + ... + n$ you can also use sets below the Sigma e.g. $\Sigma_{i\in\{1,2,3\}} i = 1 + 3 +2$ or sum over an array $\Sigma_{i = 0}^{n-1} = a[i]$ (where $a$ is an array of length $n$). Thus if you write your program as a formula you should use Sigma $\Sigma$ only for sums. There other mathematical symbols for other operations such as Pi $\Pi$ for multiplication. Using $p$ below Sigma ($\Sigma_p$) doesn't really make sense.

Comment: If you e.g. sum over all pairs of values in $p$ the result of your program could be expressed as $y = \Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}\Sigma_{j=0}^{n-1} p[i]+p[j]$. ($p$ has length $n$) Instead of taking values out of the array as in your python program in math notation you usually use indices.

Comment: What do you mean by "translate Python code to math notation"?

Comment: "do something" is not compatible with the summation notation. A correct formulation would be "accumulate a function of $a, b$".

Answer (score 0):

The $\sum$ notation is specifically summation. There is also product notation:

$$n! = \prod_{i=1}^{n} i $$

But I think what you want is some kind of Zermelo-Fraenkel notation?

$$\left\{ f(a,b)\,|\,a,b \in P \right\}$$

Comment: The set notation is also incorrect, unless the behavior being described is to return a set of values. The line `do something with a and b` in the original code is inherently imperative; there is no fully literal translation of it into a functional notation without using monad `mapM` or something.

Comment: What's the "something"?

Comment: If you want a mathematical-style notation, you could use any of the variety of techniques for formalizing imperative semantics, e.g. Hoare logic, the various operational semantics approaches, etc. If you want to use a functional programming notation, you could use Haskell-style monads as I said, Clean/Mercury-style uniqueness types, etc. I can turn this into an answer if you think it makes sense to do so.

Answer (score 0):

That would be

$$\sum_{a\in p}\sum_{b\in p}\delta_{ab}$$

if we assume that you want to count the number of duplicate elements in $p$, using the Kronecker delta notation.

This works for $p$ being a set. In case of a sequence $p_k$ of length $n$,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\delta_{p_ip_j}$$